# Why php5-fpm hangs every 30-45 sec causes 504 bad getaway with Nginx over Linux?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'd configured an AWS server for both my Magento and Wordpress sites (2 of each). My based config was:

- Nginx
- Mysql
- Php

This sites and server worked over the last 2 years without any major issues, recently i had to migrate to a new EC2 server Instance and there the issues started. Then i realised that the web sites weren't available for less than a minute after restarting the Nginx and started throwing "502 Bad getaway"

My nginx hosts files have this php configuration.

```
location ~ .php$ { 
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    ## Tweak fastcgi buffers, just in case.
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

Then i dinged a bit deeper and found that the cause of the error was not Nginx it self, the service php5-fpm was collapsing every 30 or 45 second even with very low traffic over the websites.

For now am running a cronjob that restarts the php5-fpm service every 30 seconds. I know this is killing a fly with a Bazooka but for now it keeps the sites up and running.

Any Help would be very very Helpful!

Comment: I think the delay is caused by `IF` in your config, as stated in Nginx docs, `IF is Evil, don't use it`

Comment: Hmm thanks for pointing that detail i'll check that out!